# How to generate s3 custom error page when url expire

Tags: amazon-s3

We have generated s3 pre-signed download url using java sdk. Now when it expires an xml error page comes like

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<X-Amz-Expires>43198</X-Amz-Expires>
<Expires>2016-07-11T20:32:43Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2016-07-12T05:53:18Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>76FF61E84B37E053</RequestId>
<HostId>
S3YVhGnr+7C9fFbjaKGhGyBHIaq/Y8j8jHmfC7P31zgydJr`enter code here`QAYqROb8U1+Eq5CyV7u+OLItkd+0=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Instead of this we want a custom page to come. We are not hosting any website, simply wish to download some excel file from bucket.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with S3 pre signed urls at the moment.

- Only seems to be supported for S3 *static website hosting* solution : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CustomErrorDocSupport.html
- To see if it is supported yet check [this search on the s3 docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation-guide&searchQuery=custom+error&x=0&y=0&this_doc_product=Amazon+Simple+Storage+Service&this_doc_guide=Developer+Guide&doc_locale=en_us#facet_doc_product=Amazon%20Simple%20Storage%20Service&facet_doc_guide=Developer%20Guide)

Comment: That's unfortunate